# Delete Chapter, section etc.. titles from pdf body only include them in TOC

Tags: latexmk, report, dvi-mode

I want chapter, section, subsections in TOC but I do not want them in the pdf body as 1 title occupies entire page. I have already put the chapter names, section names etc in headers. So the only task is now to remove the chapter, section titles from pdf body.

---

sorry to trouble you.Please find below my minimal example,Image1: current output Image2: Desired ouput.

[image: Current Output:]

[image: Desired Output]

Comment: If you have written a header, wouldn't it be enough to write a toc-entry and leave out the body completely?

Comment: Thanks for the response.How to do that? I mean how to link TOC and headers?which also appears in sidebar.Please advise.

Comment: @ Johannes_B Can you please tell me how to write toc entry with headers?

Comment: I posted an answer but i really don't see the point here. You might want to add a few explanations and an [example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/) to the question.

Comment: Maybe you could define your sections like this `\section[title for TOC]{}`.  I think this would result only in a section number in the body, with no title text.

Comment: Hi @James, I am currently displaying my chapter,section.. number and tittles in headers already so I want my toc to point to that.... Currently the problem I am facing is my tittle or numbers is printed in one page and body is starting from an other page.

Answer (score 1):

I am really not sure if this is what you want, i don't see any use in it.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\fakechap}[1]{%
\cleardoublepage%
\phantomsection
\addxcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
\addchapmark{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\fakesec}[1]{%
\phantomsection
\addxcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
\addsecmark{#1}%
}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\fakechap{Walzing Wombat}
\blindtext[15]
\section{anticipating Ant}
\fakechap{Wobbling Walrus}
\blindtext[15]
\section{beautiful butterfly}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello @Johannes_B, I used the above code in my report but i get 'undefined control sequence' error so couldnot produce any ouput

Comment: Which control sequence is undefined?

Comment: @Johnnes_B \fakechap is undefined control sequence itseams.

Comment: Well, the command is introdued in my example. Have you tried the minimal example, as it it?

Comment: I have tried with my example and with your tags...but dnt use scrbook as i am using report class

Comment: @latex Please add that information as well as what it is you want to achieve to the question. Best done using a [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/).

Comment: Can you tell me why my chapter , section tittles are not immediatly followed by body why is it wasting full page.Also the browser pane when clicked on chapter takes to this page which has only tittle in it ...again i have to scroll down to see the content :(

Comment: How would i know, the behaviour is non-standard and i am not sure what you are trying to patch. Best to give a MWE. I bet you used some template that is floating around the web, which is just crappy.

Comment: I am using a turbo template which is later converted to latex.... I want to give an example but I am unable to upload my output .I am new to this site so pasting o/p here is not visible .....

Comment: I don't know what a *turbo template* might mean. To be honest, i am not psychic, i need some collaboration, i.e. relevant information from you.

Comment: sorry to trouble you.Please find below my minimal example,So in below, The first Image shows current output and second image shows the desired output .

Comment: A screenshot is something i cannot work with, please provide a [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/) <- Link